# Make Task Manager Sort by Base Name on Startup

Tags: windows-xp, boot, automation, task-manager

The Windows XP Task Manager saves most of the settings, but every time it starts, it always sorts the processes by PID. I want it to start up sorted by process name (Base Name column) since I **always** end up clicking the column header to do that when I start Task Manager anyway.

Is there a way to get this to work? I have looked at the Task Manager settings in the registry, but they are not in any sort of human-readable format.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had considered hacking the executable file (`taskmgr.exe`) to see if there were a way to build this into it, but went with a decidedly easier and less risky method.

Since it amounts to a standard list-view control, what I did was to write an application that can detect if Task Manager is running, and if so, to hook into its list-control and perform the sort (by simulating a column click; I didn’t feel like manually sorting). It took a while to get it to be flexible enough to account for variations (especially since the columns are customizable), and then to allow for sorting on a different column—I figured I may as well have the option.

Unfortunately it means an extra program running in the background, but I already have plans for incorporating it into a more general-purpose app so that it’s not a one-function process, thus making it more acceptable to have it running because it does more things.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed that the Task Manager in Windows 7 *does* save the sort column and direction.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Task Manager doesn't do this, but I'm fairly certain [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) saves your view each time you start it.  It also has a lot more functionality and has an option to replace task manager completely.

Comment: Thanks; I’m very familiar with Mark’s tools. Unfortunately ProcExp is much more resource hungry than TaskMgr on an older system like mine.

I wonder if there is a way to hack it… I’ll give it a try soon.

Answer (score 1):

As [Tom's Hardware claims](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/53138-45-setting-default-sort-task-manger), the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\TaskManager` has 2 settings that may hold the default column sort order. Unfortunately, the data is in hex and I have no idea what the settings correspond to specifically. Perhaps Synetech can figure it out?

Comment: Thanks for the reference; I’ll look into it. However, if it is stored, then why is it not *re*-stored when you run the TaskManager? I wonder if it is a bug… Then again, that person said **possibly** through those settings, so I suspect that it is not in fact saved.